# Cannot open Office 2007 files in Windows 8

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, windows-8-upgrade

I upgraded from Windows Vista to Windows 8 and now none of my Office 2007 documents open. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have Office installed? if not, do so, if it is already installed try running the "repair" option in the "Programs and Features". Lastly if that doesn't work, check and make sure that your documents are associated with the appropriate portion of Office. docx-Word, xlsx - Excel, and so on...

Comment: Yes, I have MS Office 2007 Pro installed. I will run the repair and just reinstall if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: What happens when you try to open a file? An error message? Nothing? Are you able to associate the filetype with the application?